# Is there a way to dynamically pick a type from interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

as the title says, I tried to dynamically get the type from interface based on the key I receive in a function.

Example:

```js
interface State {
    foo: boolean;
    bar: string;
    baz: number;
}

const globalState: State = {
    foo: true,
    bar: 'somethin',
    baz: 42,
}

const update = (key: keyof State, newValue: /* TYPE ME PLZ */): State => {
    globalState[key] = newValue;
    return globalState;
}
```

Unfortunately, this causes error `Type '<INSERTED_TYPE>' is not assignable to type 'never'`

The closest I got is something like this `State[keyof State]`, but is it totally unrelated to the key I receive in the function.

**My question**: Is there a way to get the type of the `newValue` parameter?

**Bonus question**: Why is the type in the error message `never`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) for this:

```
const update = <K extends keyof State>(key: K, newValue: State[K]): State => {
    globalState[key] = newValue;
    return globalState;
}

update('foo', true); // OK
update('foo', 1); // Error: Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'
```

Now `newValue` type is resolved according to `key` type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpZBvAUM5GAeyIC5kAjEgGwjhAG59K4pyBnMKUAcyYIpwAXuRABXALYVoTAL65cCIiE7Ie1IoOrpMEcjqwBeHM2JlkXMRAA0zQW2QBydkQkQwAC1CPbA4eQAWACZbeUVlVTEABwATXWRjAB4AaWQIAA9IEBj2ZABrCABPIhg0DEgAPgAKAsLyZOtkEAgAdwA1OGorfXKIAG1kgF0ASh74wwqTAnVNToN%202sGEptaOroh%20ZCh3MSgQNQ0tebkFaLjIKsczHwsoK2GGZAB6J%20QAeWTcM91L68aARgez1eAFEoFAiA4AIJQHiSCDgZAlCyFKIoRz-RzIYC5EBEMDIODsdjAHggOAUWgWIjIKKsOBuSBQJGlMCo9FUIi0eiOIA)